# How to move a windows form that does not have a border?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a windows form that has just one label on it. I need to be able to move the form around  on the screen when it comes up. I tried the below code like suggested in many posts on google. But I could not make it working. Anyone has any idea what is going wrong here? Thanks for any help!

```
Public Class frmmsg
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Windows Form Designer generated code here

Dim drag As Boolean
Dim mousex As Integer
Dim mousey As Integer

Private Sub frmmsg_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown, Me.MouseClick, label2.MouseClick, lblMessage.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        drag = True
        mousex = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left
        mousey = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmmsg_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove, label2.MouseMove, lblMessage.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        If drag Then
            Me.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
            Me.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - mousex
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmmsg_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp, label2.MouseUp, lblMessage.MouseUp
    drag = False
End Sub

  Sub ShowMessage(ByVal psText$)

    If Not Me.Visible Then Me.Show()

    lblMessage.Text = psText
    Me.Refresh()

  End Sub

End Class
```

'This is how the above form is invoked from a different class

```
<NonSerialized()> Private mfrmmsg As frmmsg


If IsNothing(mfrmmsg) OrElse mfrmmsg.IsDisposed Then
        mfrmmsg = New frmmsg
End If

    mfrmmsg.ShowMessage(psText)
    mfrmmsg.TopMost = True
```

Comment: explain "could not make it work" - thats how I have it coded (except for the showmessage thing)

Comment: well, I attached the mouse events on the form to the appropriate mouse event handlers above. I did put break points in each of those event handlers and when I try to move the form when it comes up as a pop up, it does not move and the break points are not hit. Thanks.